# How to differentiate $x^{\log(x)}$?

Tags: calculus

I want to differentiate $x^{\log(x)}$ with respect to $x$.
By using chain rule ($x{log(x)}\frac{1}{x}$), I got the answer $\log x$. Is it right?

Comment: You may use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%5ELog%5Bx%5D%2Cx%5D) for questions like this, so you can check the result.

Comment: No. It can be of any base.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x^{\log x}$$
$$\log y=\log x \log x=\log^2 x$$
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{2}{x}\log x$$
$$y'=\frac{2y}{x}\log x$$
$$y'=2\frac{x^{\log x}}{x}\log x$$
$$y'=2x^{\log x-1}\log x$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A common trick in these sorts of problems is to remember that $a = e^{\log a}$  (where here $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm)

Now, setting $a=x^{\log x}$, you have:

$x^{\log x} = e^{\log (x^{\log x})}$, which by properties of logarithms simplifies to $=e^{(\log x)(\log x)}$.

Now see if you can continue.

---

As per your comment above, if $\log$ is meant to be of a different base, say $\log_b$, the same tactic works.  You would have $e^{(\log_b x)(\ln x)}$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\log x$ is base $e$, let $y=x^{\log x}$. Take a logarithm of both sides to get $ \log y = \log (x^{\log x}) = \log x \log x$. Differentiate both sides to get $\frac{y'}{y}= \frac{2 \log x}{x} $  Multiplying by $y$ gives $y'=x^{\log x}\frac{2 \log x}{x}$